# Provide update to only phones for a particular version of app update

Tags: android

I have an application published on the Play Store which supports both phones and tablets.

I want to release a new version of my application but I don't want the tablets having my application to get the update of this version.

Is this possible ? If yes, how can this be achieved ?

One possible solution that came to my mind was to control the version by adding:

```
<compatible-screens>
 ...
</compatible-screens>
```

code but I am not sure of the behavior.

Comment: You can test this out by using the alpha or beta channel of your app to see how it appears on each type device.

Comment: I agree that can be achieved but it would be helpful to know it as there is a time constraint. Thanks